# Limit g flag in regex substitution to part of line?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file like this:

```
"File_name_1.dat"       "File_name_1.dat"
"File_name_2.dat"       "File_name_2.dat"
"Some_other_thing.dat"  "Some_other_thing.dat"
```

Is there a regex technique can I use to replace the underscores in only the second file name on each line, like this?

```
"File_name_1.dat"       "File name 1.dat"
"File_name_2.dat"       "File name 2.dat"
"Some_other_thing.dat"  "Some other thing.dat"
```

I tried matching the column (\%XXc in Vim), but it seems to disable the g flag.

This only replaces the first underscore after column 25:

```
:%s/\%25c\([^_]*\)\zs_/ /g
```

This only replaces the last underscore in the line:

```
:%s/\%25c\(.*\)\zs_/ /g
```

I know I could repeat that command until they're gone, but I was wondering if there is a slicker way to do it.

Comment: are you able to apply any other approaches except vim substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to do this with visual selections. It's convenient that your data is layed out nicely, otherwise this wouldn't work.

- Visually select all of the second filenames
- Run this regex:

  ```
  :'<,'>s/\%V_/ /g
  ```

  The `\%V` will restrict your substitute to the inside of the current visual selection. Here's a screen shot of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Ah awesome!  I've tried block selection, but didn't think to use a \%V.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to do this. Since the data is formatted nicely I would probably visually select  and delete the first column (with `<c-v>`), Then run `:%s/_/ /g`. Then paste back the first column.

If you really wanted to do this in a single regex, you would need to use a lookbehind

```
:%s/\(\%25c.\{-}\)\@<=_/ /g
```

Where `\@<=` matches if the preceding element matches. `:help \@<=`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that lookbehind pattern.